# pass xincludes without parsing

Tags: xslt-2.0, xinclude

I've seen many question on resolving xinclude, but I haven't seen one about the opposite.

I have a source XML file with xincludes. I don't want to resolve them, but simply pass them through the XSLT with no changes. However, my parser is trying to resolve them. How can I get around this?

I'm using Saxon within Oxygen.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It's in Preferences under XML Parser in Oxygen.